# create zf2 query 'not in' clause using uninon

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I want to use union queries result in `Not in` in ZF2. Result of this query will return

```
Query: $selectLevelTwoPointFive->combine($selectLevelAll, 'UNION');
Result: ( SELECT `assigned`.`item_id` AS `item_id` FROM `assign_items_level_twopointfive` AS `assigned` ) UNION ( SELECT `assigned`.`item_id` AS `item_id` FROM `assign_items` AS `assigned` )
```

Now I want to use this query's result in 'not in' clause.

```
$select = $sql->select()->from(array(
                    "items" => "cu_items"
            ))->columns(array('item_name'=>  new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression(" group_concat(`items`.`item_name`)") ));            

            $select->join(array(
                "ca" => "cu_areas"
            ), new Expression(" ca.area_id = items.area_id ")
             , array(
                'area_name'
            ), $selectLevelAll::JOIN_INNER);
 $select->where->addPredicate(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('items.item_id NOT IN (?)',
                            array($selectLevelTwoPointFive)));
```

The result is:

```
SELECT group_concat(`items`.`item_name`) AS `item_name`, `ca`.`area_name` AS `area_name` FROM `cu_items` AS `items` INNER JOIN `cu_areas` AS `ca` ON ca.area_id = items.area_id WHERE `items`.`is_opted` = 'yes' AND `ca`.`is_opted` = 'yes' AND items.item_id NOT IN ((( SELECT `assigned`.`item_id` AS `item_id` FROM `assign_items_level_twopointfive` AS `assigned` ) UNION ( SELECT `assigned`.`item_id` AS `item_id` FROM `assign_items` AS `assigned` )))
```

It is showing mysql error :
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ( SELECT`assigned`.`item_id`AS`item_id`FROM`assign_items`AS`assigne' at line 1`

My required query is:

```
SELECT group_concat(items.item_name) AS item_name, ca.area_name AS area_name FROM cu_items
 AS items INNER JOIN cu_areas AS ca ON ca.area_id = items.area_id
 WHERE items.is_opted = 'yes' AND ca.is_opted = 'yes' AND items.item_id NOT IN 
(
    (
        SELECT assigned.item_id AS item_id FROM assign_items_level_twopointfive AS assigned  
        UNION ( SELECT assigned.item_id AS item_id FROM assign_items AS assigned )
    )
)
```

Actually when i use combine() it adds round bracket (first query) union (second query)  But `in not` I need first query union second query.

Please help. If any one suggest the mysql changes it also fine.

Comment: Please edit your question properly. Put 4 white-spaces before every line of your code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God, Find the page.
We need to override the `setSpecification()`
Here is the link for the answer.
[we can override the query output](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4680)